# Navigation service from forms to iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

I need to acmes view controller from forms page. Is there anything like this for IOS

is there any version of this in droid in iOS

```
public class NavigationImplementation : INavigationContract
{
public void Push()
{
var second = new Intent(MainActivity.activity, typeof(ScannerActivity));
MainActivity.activity.StartActivity(second);
}
}
```

Comment: use a custom renderer

Comment: what do you mean use custom render? I have created Dependency service that inherits from INavigationSerice so that works fine for droid but not sure how to display native iOS page

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin iOS, there are two ways to navigate to next page.

One is **[NavigationController Push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uinavigationcontroller.pushviewcontroller?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#UIKit_UINavigationController_PushViewController_UIKit_UIViewController_System_Boolean_)**, another is **[Model Push](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiviewcontroller.presentviewcontroller?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12#UIKit_UIViewController_PresentViewController_UIKit_UIViewController_System_Boolean_System_Action_)**.

NavigationController Push:

```
public void Push()
{
    //SecondViewController secondViewController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController;
    SecondViewController secondViewController = new SecondViewController();
    if (secondViewController!= null) {
        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(secondViewController , true);
    } 
}
```

Model Push:

```
//SecondViewController secondViewController = this.Storyboard.InstantiateViewController("SecondViewController") as SecondViewController;
SecondViewController secondViewController = new SecondViewController();
this.PresentViewController(secondViewController , true, () => { Console.WriteLine("Push completely"); });
```

Comment: Hi, this is done from Xamarin forms? I don't have storyboard

Comment: @brucaqs Okey, you can use `new SecondViewController` to generate a controller instance. I have update the asnwer.